Repeaters for transatlantic communications cables
The repeaters for the first transatlantic telephone cable TAT-1 were build with special vacuum tubes developed for that purpose. TAT-1 was in service between 1956 and 1978.
A few years later TAT-2 (1959–1982) and TAT-3 (1963–1986) were built. The distance between the repeaters was decreased to achieve more bandwidth.
TAT-1 to TAT-7 were built with coaxial cables.
TAT-8 (1988–2002) was the first fiber optic cable.
TAT-5 (1970-1993) used the SG repeater with silicon planar transistors.
There was an earlier SF repeater built with germanium mesa transistors.
The SF repeater may have been used for TAT-3 and TAT-4, but I did not find a reference yet.
Which transatlantic cable was the first one built with germanium transistors?
All electronic parts used within the repeaters had to be extremely reliable and durable. Lifespan tests of the vacuum tubes were carried out for up to 17 years, so the solid state semiconductors used after the tubes also had to have a comparably high level of reliability.

At stable, preferably low temperatures and low stress levels, semiconductor devices are quite capable of long life times, 17 years should not be a problem

The lifespan tests of the tubes were 17 years, but TAT-1 was in service over 22 years. Not a single failure of the 306 tubes.

In my previous employer (i was there from '12-'18) we regularly got safety instruments with serial numbers from the early to mid nineties back from the field for service where all we had to do was air out the insides, wipe dust off the optics and occasionally recalibrate. I think our market base at that time was just under 100k instruments. Most other services were instruments exposed to excessive temperatures. Even then it was usually not the semiconductors that died. Electrolytic caps aren't necessarily too happy about being held at 90-95C ambient for too long
